# Java JTable Result From Database

Tags: java, database, swing, jdbc, jtable

I have a problem regarding my JTable, I don't know how can I store my fetch records which is of type String from my database to the multidimensional array which is let's say Object[][] data. What I want to do is show my database records to the JTable, I already fetch the records in dtabase and store it in my String variables, The question is how can I store the fetch records to the multidimensional array of Object and use it on my JTable.

Here are my code for fetching records:

```
static class TableData{
    Object[][] data;
    int count = 0;
    Statement sql = null;
    String query, user = "JEROME", pass = "Perbert101", driver = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", conString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE";
    Connection con = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    TableData(){
        try{
            Class.forName(driver);
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Problem Loading Driver");
        }
        try{
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(conString, user, pass);
            sql = con.createStatement();
            sql.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM INVENTORY");
            rs = sql.getResultSet();
            int key = 0;
            String val = null, val1 = null, val2 = null, val3 = null, val4 = null, val5 = null;
            System.out.println("Results: ");
            while(rs.next()){


                    key = rs.getInt(1);
                    if(rs.wasNull()){
                        key = -1;
                    }
                    val = rs.getString(2);
                    if(rs.wasNull()){
                        val = null;
                    }
                    val1 = rs.getString(3);
                    if(rs.wasNull()){
                        val = null;
                    }
                    val2 = rs.getString(4);
                    if(rs.wasNull()){
                        val = null;
                    }

                    val3 = rs.getString(5);
                    if(rs.wasNull()){
                        val = null;
                    }
                    val4 = rs.getString(6);
                    if(rs.wasNull()){
                        val = null;
                    }
                    val5 = rs.getString(7);
                    if(rs.wasNull()){
                        val = null;
                    }

                System.out.println("Key = " + key);
                System.out.println("value = " + val);
                System.out.println("value = " + val1);
                System.out.println("value = " + val2);
                System.out.println("value = " + val3);
                System.out.println("value = " + val4);
                System.out.println("value = " + val5);

            }


            sql.close();
            con.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Loading Database Data");
        }

    }
}
//----------END------------
public static void main(String[] args){
    POSModel.TableData data = new POSModel.TableData();
}
```

Comment: yep, I'm noob on Java and it takes me for about 1 hour studying on how to get some records, can you help me? I really need this right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that the data you're pulling from the database needs to be stored in an array (by columns) first...

```
Object[] rowData = new Object[7];
rowData[0] = key;
rowData[1] = val;
rowData[2] = val1;
rowData[3] = val2;
rowData[4] = val3;
rowData[5] = val4;
rowData[6] = val5;
```

This then needs to be stored in some kind of row structure, I'd personally use a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).  The main reason for this choice is that you probably don't know in advance the number of rows you will be reading...

```
List<Object[]> rowList = new ArrayList<Object[]>(25);

// Process the resultset...
// Create the column array from above...

rowList.add(rowData);
```

Once you've completed reading all the rows, you need to convert the list it an array...

```
data = rowList.toArray(new Object[](rowList.size())); // I like to provide my own array
```

Equally, you could do...

```
data = new Object[rowList.size()][7];
rowList.toArray(data);
```

Which ever is more convenient...

Now you should have a 2D array...

Comment: How can I for loop a multidimensional array? so that I don't need to type all the fetch records.

Comment: It seems like it doesn't accept the keyword 'List' is this really a java keyword? or a generic class which needed to be created first before using?

Comment: It's not a keyword, it's an inteface, from `java.util.List`. Which `java.util.ArrayList` is an implementation of...

Comment: Okay  understand it's an interface from the util library, The 'Create the columns array above' that you commented is that the place where I'll put my code, which is the fetching of the records, right?

Comment: I'd create the list right before the `while(rs.next()){` statement. Each `Object` array needs to be created within this while loop (and added to the list)

Comment: it's working now, once i try the System.out.println(data[0][1]) it print all the column 1. Thanks a lot I think list is much easier to rather than typing multiple for loops, thanks again.